# deleting cookies in java

Tags: java, cookies

I used the below code in my java class to delete my cookies. I am using struts framework.

```
cookie.setValue("");
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
response.addCookie(cookie);
//code to redirect to index.jsp
```

index.jsp

```
<% Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();%>
```

In this array of cookies, why can I still see the cookie I deleted in the action class, although it's maxAge is now 0 and value is "" ?
The cookie is not visible if the page is refreshed. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 1 line to delete the cookie

```
cookie.setPath("/");

cookie.setValue("");
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to understand the creation/deletion of cookies.
We will create a cookie and delete the cookie to understand how it works.
For example, At the time of cookie creation you had following code written:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("yourCookieName", null);
cookie.setPath("/your-projectName"); //Cookie will be created with this path name.
cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10);//set cookie for 10 years of age
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

This will make a cookie having path which you have mentioned in the code. So to delete this cookie created for 10 years, we should have following code:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("yourCookieName", null);
cookie.setPath("/your-projectName"); //we need to provide same path 
                                     //as we had at time of creation
cookie.setMaxAge(0);//max age is set to 0
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

If we do not keep the same path name the cookie won't be deleted.
Similarly if you created a cookie with different path and delete with different path it won't be deleted. You can also check the changes of cookie in the browser to see at what time it expires.